# Capture Barcode input into one single String

Tags: java, arrays, string, barcode

Ive been trying to work it out but cant get to no solution, im sure its something simple that im doing wrong. But im trying to capture the input into one simple String. I tried adding the keys into an array and try to convert them to a string but to no avail.

This is my basic code

```
                        @Override
                    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
                         if(e.getKeyCode() >=48 && e.getKeyCode() <=57){
                             String myString = Character.toString(e.getKeyChar());
                             keys.add(myString);
                        }
                         System.out.println(keys);
                    }
                });
```

When doing this my output is :

```
[4, 2]
[4, 2, 2]
[4, 2, 2, 1]
[4, 2, 2, 1, 1]
[4, 2, 2, 1, 1, 4]
[4, 2, 2, 1, 1, 4, 7]
[4, 2, 2, 1, 1, 4, 7, 1]
[4, 2, 2, 1, 1, 4, 7, 1]
[4, 2, 2, 1, 1, 4, 7, 1]
[4, 2, 2, 1, 1, 4, 7, 1]
```

The last few entries are the correct barcode but i cant seperate them using:

```
String barcode = keys.get(keys.size() - 1);
```

When i print the barcode i get

```
4
2
2
1
1
4
7
1
1
1
1
```

which is wrong as there are extra numbers and it isn't one single string without spaces.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like `keys` - is List.So when you are trying to print it, Java prints the result of `toString` function (similar to this `[4, 2, 2, 1, 1, 4, 7]`). But with `keys.get(n)` you are getting only last element from this List.

Try this:
`String barcode = keys.toString()`.

By the way, you have some extra numbers because of evaluating `keyPressed` function, which appends new values to your `keys` List.

Comment: thanks, i will try it once i get home from work. Regards

Comment: No, no luck. I'm getting [4]
[4, 2]
[4, 2, 2]
[4, 2, 2, 1]
[4, 2, 2, 1, 1]
[4, 2, 2, 1, 1, 4]
[4, 2, 2, 1, 1, 4, 7]
[4, 2, 2, 1, 1, 4, 7, 1]
[4, 2, 2, 1, 1, 4, 7, 1] like the earlier output. Any more ideas?